# Cómo saltar credenciales de FTP en Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Tengo un problema con un wordpress que instale hace poco, pasa que cuando quiero instalar algo me salta una pantalla que me pide credenciales de FTP, a lo cual jamas he tenido que colocar eso en ningún wordpress que he instalado, quisiera saber como puedo solucionar esto porque coloco mis datos de FTP y me salen errores como que usuario o contraseña incorrecta o conexión fallida, he probado una de las opciones que dice wordpress, a lo cual ya no aparece la pantalla que pide credenciales de FTP pero igual no me deja instalar nada me dice error.

este es código que probé:

```
define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');
```

y también:

```
define("FTP_HOST", "localhost");
define("FTP_USER", "yourftpusername");
define("FTP_PASS", "yourftppassword");
```

gracias por sus aportes.

Answer (score 0):

Si ya has puesto en el config el FS_METHOD a direct, entonces parece que se trata de un problema de permisos.

Si usas apache y está por defecto, prueba a cambiar el propietario de las carpetas y ficheros:

```
chown www-data:www-data -R /var/www
```

Pero esto solo funcionará si tienes la web en /var/www y el usuario de apache es www-data. Cambia estos valores a los de tu interés.